# Why does my plot of the Blackman window not match everyone else's in literature?

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, window-functions, stft, window

I've seen the plot for Blackman window as so in a bunch of books, as on [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/blackman.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com) website:

[image]

But plotting the same equation on [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%200.42%20-%200.5*cos(2*pi*x%2F200)%20%2B%200.08*cos(2*pi*x%2F200)) yields a different plot:

[image]

Why is their graph not centered around 0? And why is their peak at y=1?

Comment: You Wolfram query is [wrong](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+0.42+-+0.5*cos%282*pi*x%2F63%29+%2B+0.08*cos%284*pi*x%2F63%29)

Comment: SE.DSP wishes you a happy new year 2017, with a kind reminder that your question and its answers may require some action (update, votes, acceptance, etc.)

Comment: Thanks @LaurentDuval. Action executed. Wish you a happy new year as well!

Comment: For some reason literature insists on defining window functions as between 0 and N-1, which I find unhelpful, the sinc function being zero-centred for instance. To make the Blackman window centred on 0 simply turn `- 0.5` into `+ 0.5`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a missing $2\times$ factor inside the second cosine, and you get a centered $201$ point windows with the change of variable $x-100$. See at [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%200.42%20-%200.5*cos(2*pi*x%2F200)%20%2B%200.08*cos(4*pi*x%2F200)):

$$ 0.42 - 0.5*\cos\left(2\pi\frac{x-100}{200}\right) + 0.08 \cos\left(4\pi\frac{x-100}{200}\right)\,.$$